# About function invoking in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, syntax, invoke

I run a node.js server, and when I navigate to `/foo/bar` it enters `router.get()`, but why does it also enters the `mongodb.MongoClient.connect()`?

Where was it invoked?

```
var mongodb = require('mongodb');

router.get('/foo/bar', function (req, res) {
    console.log("in router get");

    mongodb.MongoClient.connect(uri, function(error, db) {
            console.log("in mongo db");

    });
});
```

Comment: When you navigate to `/foo/bar` the callback function `function (req, res)...` is called. So it is normal that `connect` is called

Comment: Is this a normal behavior of `connect`? or a callback always invokes function definitions inside? @ThomasThiebaud

Comment: When a callback is executed, it "invokes" the functions inside

Comment: Coming from compiled languages, it's not very WYSIWYG... @ThomasThiebaud

Comment: @kuhaku: It's nothing to do with compiled vs. scripted (and in fact, the first thing NodeJS does with a script is hand it off to V8 to compile it). If you have a Java background, it's like passing a `Runnable` into `router.get`. If you have a C# background, it's like passing an `Action<T>` or related delegate to it.

Comment: I get the callback, it's also like passing a lambda as a runnable, but it's just strange seeing a function definition that's also being invoked without explicitly calling it. There's not even a `();` at the end of that function definition. @T.J.Crowder

Comment: @kuhaku: Right, because the code there *isn't* calling it, it's just defining it. Somewhere inside Express's routing mechanism, there will indeed be a *call* to it, e.g. something like: `route.callback(req, res);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I run a node.js server, and when I navigate to /foo/bar it enters `router.get()`

Actually no, it enters `router.get` on *startup*, before you navigate to `/foo/bar`, and does so only once.

> but why does it also enters the mongodb.MongoClient.connect()?

Because that's the purpose of [`router.get`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#router.METHOD): To tell Express (the library being used for this) that when there's a request for `/foo/bar`, it should run the given callback. So when you navigate to `/foo/bar`, Express calls the callback, and the callback's code calls `mongodb.MongoClient.connect`. This happens repeatedly, any time there's a request to the server for `/foo/bar`.

Comment: So if there are several `router.get()` with different paths, are all of them invoked on startup?

Comment: @kuhaku: All of them are *called* on startup (provided there's no branching logic in the script calling them), but again, their *callbacks* aren't called until/unless a request with a matching path is made to the server.